# Perl: Script for finding world-writable files not finding world-writable files

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script which was designed to scan locally mounted file systems for world-writable files. Part of its execution is to read in a list of excluded files and build a hash from them. Each file is then checked for existence in the hash to determine if it is, in fact, excluded.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl ':mode';
use File::Find;
no warnings 'File::Find';
no warnings 'uninitialized';

my $dir = "/var/log/tivoli/";
my $mtab = "/etc/mtab";
my $permFile = "world_writable_w_files.txt";
my $tmpFile = "world_writable_files.tmp";
my $exclude = "/usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt";
#my $mask = (S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH);
my (%excludes, %devNums);
my ($regExcld, $errHeader);

# Compile a list of mountpoints that need to be scanned
my @mounts;

open MT, "<${mtab}" or die "Cannot open ${mtab}, $!";

# We only want the local mountpoints
while (<MT>) {
  if ($_ =~ /ext[34]/) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split;
    push(@mounts, $line[1]);
    my @stats = stat($_);
    $devNums{$stats[0]} = $_;
  }
}

close MT;

# Build a hash of each mountpoint's device number for future comparison
#foreach (@mounts) {
#  my @stats = stat($_);
#  $devNums{$stats[0]} = $_;
#}

# Build a hash from /usr/local/etc/world_writables_excludes.txt
if ((! -e $exclude) || (-z $exclude)) {
  $errHeader = <<HEADER;
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!                                                  !!
!! /usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt is    !!
!! is missing or empty. This report includes        !!
!! every world-writable file including those which  !!
!! are expected and should be excluded.             !!
!!                                                  !!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


HEADER

} else {
  open XCLD, "<${exclude}" or die "Cannot open ${exclude}, $!\n";
  while (<XCLD>) {
    chomp;
    $excludes{$_} = 1;
  }
}

sub wanted {
  # Is it excluded from the report...
  return if (exists $excludes{$File::Find::name});

  # ...in a basic directory, ...
  return if $File::Find::dir =~ /sys|proc|dev/;

  # ...a regular file, ...
  return unless -f;

  # ...local, ...
  my @dirStats = stat($File::Find::name);
  return if (exists $devNums{$dirStats[0]});

  # ...and world writable?
#  return unless $dirStats[2] & $mask == $mask;
  return unless (((stat)[2] & S_IWUSR) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWGRP) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWOTH));

  # If so, add the file to the list of world writable files
  print(WWFILE "$File::Find::name\n");

}

# Create the output file path if it doesn't already exist.
mkdir($dir or die "Cannot execute mkdir on ${dir}, $!") unless (-d $dir);

# Create our filehandle for writing our findings
open WWFILE, ">${dir}${tmpFile}" or die "Cannot open ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";
print(WWFILE "${errHeader}") if ($errHeader);

find(\&wanted, @mounts);

close WWFILE;

# If no world-writable files have been found ${tmpFile} should be zero-size;
# Delete it so Tivoli won't alert
if (-z "${dir}${tmpFile}") {
  unlink "${dir}${tmpFile}";

} else {
  rename("${dir}${tmpFile}","${dir}${permFile}") or die "Cannot rename file ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";

}
```

The problem appears to be the comparison to the hash containing the list of excluded files.

The creation of the hash:

```
} else {
  open XCLD, "<${exclude}" or die "Cannot open ${exclude}, $!\n";
  while (<XCLD>) {
    chomp;
    $excludes{$_} = 1;
  }
}
```

...and the comparison...

```
  # Is it excluded from the report...
  return if (exists $excludes{$File::Find::name});
```

I made this determination after reverting to a previous method of building a regex from the list of excluded files

```
# Read in the list of excluded files and create a regex from them
my $regExcld = do {
  open XCLD, "<${exclude}" or die "Cannot open ${exclude}, $!\n";
  my @ignore = <XCLD>;
  chomp @ignore;
  local $" = '|';
  qr/@ignore/;

};
```

(Side-note: I was told I haven't properly anchored the regex. I'm not sure what I should be doing.)

And:

```
# Is it excluded from the report...
return if $File::Find::name =~ $regExcld;
```

I personally wouldn't have an issue with the regex method, however, I'm going for optimal performance and if the list of excludes grows the regex grows and the time increases.

I'm certain that the %excludes hash is being properly populated as I've printed out the contents during a script test run.

Where is the error in my script?

EDIT 1:
I'm making incremental progress with this. I have swapped out the script above with the script I just ran which found all of the files I expected to find. Unfortunately, it also found the file which it should not have found (one of the excludes). That one file, in fact, was written to the report twice.

Also of note is the fact that I made a change as suggested by @Borodin and used a `$mask` variable which would be used to run a bitwise comparison to `$dirStats[2]` within the `wanted` subroutine. This actually didn't work and returned every file on the server in addition to returning an error which stated `possible precedence problem on bitwise & operator` pointing to line 107 where I had made the change. I have since reverted back to performing `stat` three times on each file.

EDIT 2:
I asked in another forum and was pointed to the fact that I need to place parens around the bitwise AND (which @Borodin also caught in his suggestion and corrected it):

```
return unless ($dirStats[2] & $mask) == $mask;
```

This has eliminated the `Possible precedence` error. I am still, however, getting the output which includes files which should be explicitly ignored as well as writing said files to the output file twice.

EDIT 3:
Turns out the script was working as expected. The file being found was *not* in the list of excludes. It was similar, but the path had an extra directory.

Comment: have you tried to print your %excludes hash, to check if it indeed contains what it should contain?

Comment: @Ashalynd And I quote: "I'm certain that the %excludes hash is being properly populated as I've printed out the contents during a script test run."

Comment: The lack of anchoring on your regex means that you will match file names that *contain* any of the strings in `@ignore`. Instead you should write `qr/\A(?:@ignore)\z/`

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is the hash method not excluding files when it should? Does the regex method work?

Comment: @Borodin Thanks. I'll make that change in case no fixes for the hash comparison are pointed out.

Comment: @Borodin The regex method does work, but as I mentioned, as the list grows to potentially hundreds of files (due to an application agent which inexplicably sets every file to be world writable) the execution time could increase to an unacceptable level. The hash method is actually excluding files which should _not_ be excluded. I have created one file explicitly for testing the script. It is found and written to the report using the regex method, but not when using the hash method. It is not in the list of excluded files and, as I've verified, is not in the hash.

Comment: I can't see how a hash test can give you a false positive. I suggest you put *both* exclusion tests in the `wanted` subroutine and compare the decisions they make. If you pass to `find` just the directory where your test file is then your tests will be much quicker

Comment: By the way, you should be using the `@dirStats` array that you've populated instead of calling `stat` three more times for each file. You should also create a bit mask `my $mask = S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH` and you can then say `unless $dirStats[2] & $mask == $mask`. But of course that's irrelevant to your immediate problem

Comment: The script does more, of course, but you should be aware you can find a list of files with world writable permissions with the GNU find command as:  `find . -type f -perm -0002 `

Comment: @Borodin I don't know which other exclusion test you mean. Are you referring to the `@mounts` array? I'm not sure I understand what you are saying about the @dirStats array. Can you put it in context of my script?

Comment: @Borodin I believe you mean `return unless $dirStats[2] & $mask == $mask`.

Comment: @Borodin After making the `$mask` change I'm getting `Possible precedence problem on bitwise & operator at ./ww_files-v4-2.pl line 107.`

Comment: @theillien:  **a)** I meant use both the hash *and* the regex and print the file names where one excludes the file and the other does not **b)** I mean that you save the result of `stat` in `@dirStat` which you could use in the following test for permissions, but you call `stat` again three times instead **c)** Yes, I'm sorry, it needs some parentheses. It should be `return unless ($dirStats[2] & $mask) == $mask`

Comment: @Borodin I figured the second part. I tried it but it didn't work. I only got the error mentioned in my previous comment and it returned every file on the file system rather than only those I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the script in its final form:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl ':mode';
use File::Find;
no warnings 'File::Find';
no warnings 'uninitialized';

my $dir = "/var/log/tivoli/";
my $mtab = "/etc/mtab";
my $permFile = "world_writable_files.txt";
my $tmpFile = "world_writable_files.tmp";
my $exclude = "/usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt";
my $mask = S_IWUSR && S_IWGRP && S_IWOTH;
my (%excludes, %devNums);
my ($regExcld, $errHeader);

# Compile a list of mountpoints that need to be scanned
my @mounts;

open MT, "<${mtab}" or die "Cannot open ${mtab}, $!";

# We only want the local mountpoints
while (<MT>) {
  if ($_ =~ /ext[34]/) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split;
    push(@mounts, $line[1]);
    my @stats = stat($_);
    $devNums{$stats[0]} = $_;
  }
}

close MT;

# Build a hash from /usr/local/etc/world_writables_excludes.txt
if ((! -e $exclude) || (-z $exclude)) {
  $errHeader = <<HEADER;
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!                                                  !!
!! /usr/local/etc/world_writable_excludes.txt is    !!
!! is missing or empty. This report includes        !!
!! every world-writable file including those which  !!
!! are expected and should be excluded.             !!
!!                                                  !!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


HEADER

} else {
  open XCLD, "<${exclude}" or die "Cannot open ${exclude}, $!\n";
  while (<XCLD>) {
    chomp;
    $excludes{$_} = 1;
  }
}

sub wanted {
  # Is it excluded from the report...
  return if (exists $excludes{$File::Find::name});

  # ...in a special directory, ...
  return if $File::Find::dir =~ /sys|proc|dev/;

  # ...a regular file, ...
  return unless -f;

  # ...local, ...
  my @dirStats = stat($File::Find::name);
  return if (exists $devNums{$dirStats[0]});

  # ...and world writable?
  return unless ($dirStats[2] & $mask) == $mask;
#  return unless (((stat)[2] & S_IWUSR) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWGRP) && ((stat)[2] & S_IWOTH));

  # If so, add the file to the list of world writable files
  print(WWFILE "$File::Find::name\n");

}

# Create the output file path if it doesn't already exist.
mkdir($dir or die "Cannot execute mkdir on ${dir}, $!") unless (-d $dir);

# Create our filehandle for writing our findings
open WWFILE, ">${dir}${tmpFile}" or die "Cannot open ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";
print(WWFILE "${errHeader}") if ($errHeader);

find(\&wanted, @mounts);

close WWFILE;

# If no world-writable files have been found ${tmpFile} should be zero-size;
# Delete it so Tivoli won't alert
if (-z "${dir}${tmpFile}") {
  unlink "${dir}${tmpFile}";

} else {
  rename("${dir}${tmpFile}","${dir}${permFile}") or die "Cannot rename file ${dir}${tmpFile}, $!";

}
```